# Python Tkinter: multiple images and text on a BIG button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, button, tkinter

Is it possible to mount more than one image AND text on a Tkinter button?

Or, is it possible to put a FRAME containing images + text on a button?

I want a big button containing multiple widgets that, when taken together, fully describe the option the user will be able to choose.

I appreciate any suggestions!!

Comment: I'd suggest creating the `Button`'s complete image, including all photos and text, in an image editor. Then you can simply assign that single image to the `Button`. As an aside, though, if the button requires multiple images and text to explain what it does, either A) it's too complicated or B) it should display a short description only, with a more thorough treatment of its behavior in the program's documentation.

Comment: Thanks Tigerhawk!
The problem is that  the images and the text are supposed to change periodically, within runtime. I could perfectly show them in a frame aside from the button, but I thought it would look better to have that whole frame with a button functionality. Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: btw, the idea of these big buttons is that they act like the options in a multiple choice quiz, so you just click on whatever you see is the answer, you don't need to look for the button on the side.

Comment: So, you want each button to basically hold a multimedia representation of a multiple choice question's answer? And the representation has to be able to mutate its components depending on some factor? I'm still not sure that we're solving the root problem here.

Comment: Ok so let me be more specific.
This is a sequence quizzer. 5 number cards are randomly dealt to the table (they appear as actual cards in the GUI), and 2 cards are dealt to each player.
I want the 2 cards plus the name of the player to be located on top of the button (there will be, then, one button per player).
The idea is that the user has to press the button of the player that has the two cards that complete the sequence.
For example:
CARDS ON THE TABLE: 3, 4, 5, 8, 9
PLAYER CHARLIE: 8, 5
PLAYER ANN: 7, 6
PLAYER BOBBY: 4, 6
So, out of those three big buttons, the user needs to press Ann's.

Comment: After that happens, you can press a button to deal the cards again and start a new round, so the images on each player's buttons are going to change.

Comment: If it needs to be that dynamic, I'd say you should use a [`Canvas`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) instead of `Buttons`, creating objects on the `Canvas` and parsing mouse clicks on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to mount more than one image AND text on a Tkinter button?

Strictly speaking, no, it is not possible.

> Or, is it possible to put a FRAME containing images + text on a button?

Yes, though it probably won't work on OSX. It would probably take you less time to actually try it than to type in the question on stackoverflow. A little research goes a long way.

You can also simply *not* use a button. Just use a frame or canvas, and set up bindings on the container and/or it's contents to react to a button click.

Comment: Thanks, @Bryan! I did do my research online but, since I did not find the topic mentioned in any big forums or in the Tkinter documentation, it didn't occur to me to actually try it. I just wanted to be sure of the impossibility of it.
Now, what kind of software would allow me to do what I'm looking for? Maybe PyQt or PyGame?

Comment: @PabloSotomayor: "just try it" is a remarkably powerful tool, and should be the first thing you do when you have a question. As for what you want to do, tkinter is quite capable of doing what you want. Like I said in the answer, you don't _have_ to use a button -- a frame or a label or a canvas can function exactly like a button.

Comment: Got it, thanks man!
I just set up bindings to change the relief (raised by default) when the mouse button was pressed and back to the original state when released, besides the actual command. It looks exactly like a big button. But I'm still surprised not to have found my question anywhere. I can't believe ALL questions posted on forums are THAT intelligent. :D